# Can resource files be modified in an iOS or macOS app by malicious third parties?

Tags: ios, security, md5

Let's say I release an app that contains a certificate as a resource file that I use to validate something within my app. Could a malicious third party modify that certificate in any way, thereby potentially circumventing my validation? Or are iOS apps compiled/signed/distributed in a way where modifying resource files inherently breaks it?

In case this is a danger, I could imagine an md5 checksum of the certificate file would potentially resolve the issue...but not sure if this is necessary (or even if it is safe enough).

Additional questions:

- If not by default, would jailbroken devices allow this?
- What about macOS apps where there are fewer limits?

Some more background for this thought experiment:

- the certificate itself is not a secret, so I wouldn't care about it being accessible by the 3rd party
- I understand such modification would *only* affect the app of the given 3rd party user and they would have no way of distributing it (well, at least for iOS); the question is if they could use it locally

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity